# Trying to create a log x & y-axis with data points that are sized based on a numerical variable and colored based on categorical factors

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've tried using xyplot, symbols, and plot and am not getting exactly what I'm looking for. Basically, I have x and y data that I want to plot on a log scale. Each data point will be a solid filled circle, with the circle size dependent on a numerical variable (z), and the color based on a categorical value (w). Here are things I've tried:

radius <- sqrt(z / pi)
symbols(x, y, circles=radius, inches = 0.35)

Adding in a log scale and color completely threw it off. Basically trying to do something like this (http://flowingdata.com/2010/11/23/how-to-make-bubble-charts/) minus labels, with log scales and colored by a categorical variable (w).

I also tried xyplot and plot (using cex for size of points), but couldn't quite get what I was looking for either...can anyone point me in the right direction? Just starting off learning R and appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this in ggplot:

```
ggplot(d)+
    geom_point(aes(x=Expectancy,y=Fertility,size=Population,colour=Region),alpha=0.8)+
    theme_bw()
```

To do it with log scales you would simply add :

```
+ scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. What is the "d" referenced in ggplot(d)? All of the other parts make sense, but I imagine some sort of data frame needs to be stored as d, is that right?

Comment: Ya, d is just the data.frame. This is data I grabbed from online to create the plot for you. You could just as well put the aes(x=...) in ggplot instead of geom_point(), it'll do the exact same thing.

Comment: Tried to do it that way and get "Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval"...here is how I entered the code: `code` ggplot(aes(x=xx$xxx,y=yy$yyy,size=size$Users_count,colour=color$Type),alpha=0.8) +
  theme_bw() + scale_y_log10() + scale_x_log10()

Comment: you have to tell it what data frame the data is coming from, and it all needs to be in the same data frame:

`df<-data.frame("x"=xx$xxx,"y"=yy$yyy,"s"=size$Users_count,"c"=color$Type)`
`ggplot(df,aes(x,y,size=s,colour=c))+geom_point() +scale_y_log10()+scale_x_log10()`

It needs to have geom_point() in order for it to plot points. theme_bw() is optional, it just changes the colour scheme of the plot (background etc.) to be black and white.